# How to use the C++ compiler/linker/trick to detect a value that is assigned but never subsequently referred to?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, g++, mingw

I want to make a singleton class, call it `global_references` containing a bunch of cached global values. The singleton class code will be automatically generated from a set of tables. The general scheme is something like this:

### global_references.h

```
struct global_references
{
    some_type value1;
    some_type value2;
    some_type value3;
    ...
    static const global_references& instance();
};
```

Assume that `global_references::instance()` initializes the various valueN variables and returns the singleton instance. Then various clients will used the cached values in their own code:

### some_translation_unit.cpp

```
...
x = global_references::instance().value1;
```

My concern is that I will add items to the table that is used to produce the auto-generated `global_references` class but over time, some of the symbols they generate will become obsolete and stop being used in the program. I would like to know when this happens, **preferably by having the compiler or linker complain** about an unused symbol, or a value that is assigned but never used. This will remind me to go delete the corresponding item from the table. I am also open to any other reasonably simple solution.

I am using MinGW [g++ 4.6.2] on Windows.

### Options Already Considered

I thought about making member functions to return the values, but the The `-Wunused-function` compiler option only works on static functions whereas I need `global_references` to be a modular component which I can include in any translation unit.

Comment: Why can't the `static some_time& get_value1()` return `instance().value1`?

Comment: Compiler/linker still won't catch it. I've found a static analysis tool called `cppcheck` [(link)](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) which will catch unused functions, so I might be able to go that route. It doesn't catch unused `inline` functions, however. I'm unable to understand why exactly.

Comment: `inline` functions are "created" in every compilation unit they are visible to, then all but one of them are discarded.  The tool probably cannot distinguish between multiple use and multiple instantiation?

Comment: Well it's doing static analysis so it shouldn't matter what the compiler is doing with it. A semantic analysis can be done separate from how the compiler decides to emit assembly code. I discovered that if you tell it to include the headers, it detects unused `inline` functions -- the problem is actually that it misses unused functions which are defined in headers. So `cppcheck --enable=unusedFunction *.h *.cpp` seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

Use -Wunused-but-set-variable, or for broader effect, -Wunused, or -Wall.

Comment: Sadly, it won't work. Consider this code in header "x.h". `struct x { int y; static const x& instance(); };` Suppose that `y` is initialized in "x.cpp" and "x.h" is included in "main.cpp" but nothing in "main.cpp" refers to `x::y`? How would the compiler know it's supposed to report on this when compiling translation unit "main.cpp"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understood your purpose. So, after you add items to the table each time, you will recompile the project code to find what is not used by compile-warning. It Sounds like an inefficient way.

Comment: Let me clarify. I'll be adding items to the table on an as-needs basis. However, like in all software projects, sometimes you just stop using certain symbols. Suppose initially I'm using `value3` in 3 places. Then later 2 of those uses get deleted. Then later, finally, the last reference to `value3` goes away. I want my build system to tell me that I have an unused symbol at that point!

Comment: OK. Maybe you can put all "initializ code of that variables" to the common methods like setValueN(). "common" means not inline, as you said cppcheck can not catch unused inline functions.